# Set ringtones as default ringtone or for some phone number

Tags: android-contentprovider

i want to create an app to use ringtones to set as default ringtone or set that ringtone for specific phone number. Can you help me with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw many posts but anyone showed what i should actually have to do. So i decided to create this complete answer , you can start by using this sample code...

Here is my `MainActivity.java` which i used

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {     

        @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent();  
                intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
                intent1.setType("audio/*"); 
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Choose Sound File"), 6);



            }

        });

            }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode ==RESULT_OK&&requestCode==6){
    Uri i = data.getData(); //getDATA
    String s = = i.getPath(); //getPath
    File k = new File(s); //set File from path

if(s!=null){  //(file.exists

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ring");
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k.length());
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

       Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
       getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);


       try {
           RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
       } catch (Throwable t) {

       }    
}


    }



    }



    }
```

Lastly its really important to add those permisions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for example if you dont add the permision to write external storage your app will crash like mine.. xD

**What you need:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" ></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```

You can try my app on Google Play : [BackAtel Audio Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gr.backatel.volume)

Hope that helps....